# C library, makefile header dependencies

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Let' say I have library project with a few folders:

- build: where .o files go
- lib: where the compiled static and dynamic libraries go
- src: where the .c source files go
- include: where the headers are placed

The problem is, everytime I change a header file and make doesn't perceive this (which is obvious why if you look at my Makefile) and says everything is up to date. I have manage to solve this with another project which wasn't a library, but with this one everytime I try something I end up with an error when the target is getting built. Here is the Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Iinclude -rdynamic -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS)
LDFLAGS=$(OPTLIBS)

SOURCES=$(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst src/%.c,build/%.o,$(SOURCES))

TARGET=lib/libdatastruct.a
SO_TARGET=$(patsubst %.a,%.so,$(TARGET))

# The Target lib
all: $(TARGET) $(SO_TARGET)

dev: CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Iinclude -Wall -Wextra $(OPTFLAGS)
dev: all

$(TARGET): CFLAGS += -fPIC
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $@ $(OBJECTS)
    ranlib $@
$(SO_TARGET): $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

build/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

build:
    @mkdir -p lib
    @mkdir -p build

clean:
    rm -rf lib build
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this myself. Changed this:

```
build/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

To this:

```
build/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -o $@ -c $<

include $(DEPS)

$(DEPS): ;
```

And added:

```
DEPS=$(patsubst %.o,%.d,$(OBJECTS))
```

After:

```
OBJECTS=$(patsubst src/%.c,build/%.o,$(SOURCES))
```

Comment: Great! Did other similar posts explaining how automatic dependecies can be created, help you solve this one?

Comment: @2501 This [site](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) helped. Although I don't quite get why it works. Is it creating two recipes for each .o target? Because I have that line with `build/%.o: src/%.c` and the `$(DEPS)` included are of the same form but with percentage symbols replaced by the actual filenames. Is this a normal thing to do in makefile?

Comment: I actually mean rules, not recipes. If I create multiple rules for a single target and place a recipe only on one, leaving the others empty with just the dependencies, will make always make sure the target is up to date with the dependencies?

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't seen the entire makefile. I suggest you do some research and/or ask new questions. My I ask, and I'm only curious, did you learn about the existence of automatic dependency generation from my answer?

Comment: @2501 I already knew about it and tried numerous ways, I just couldn't understand I had to provide a general rule (with the percentage signs) even if I had included the dependency file generated by gcc. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Look at the contents of the generated dependency file. It only contains code that looks like the code at the bottom in my answer, which only sets the prerequisites. You still have to provide the recipes.

Comment: @2501 Yeah, I understand that now. I originally thought that make would also provide implicit recipes​ just like it provides implicit rules.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a list of headers:

```
HEADERS := $(wildcard src/*.h)
```

and since you don't have any dependency files, simply ensure that all object files depend on all header files:

```
$(OBJECTS): $(HEADERS)
```

If any header is modified every object file is rebuild since any source file may include (and depend) on any header file.

If you don't want to rebuild everything after a header is changed, you can manually add specific dependencies, so that only the needed files are rebuilt. For example:

```
src/file.c: src/file.h
src/main.c: src/main.h src/file.h
```

Those dependencies can also be made automatically.

Comment: Is this the only way? Because it I have a modified header that is included by just one file the whole project would have to be rebuilt.

Comment: @cpassos Without any additional assumptions, yes. Any source file could include any header file, and no information about those includes is available to make.

Comment: @cpassos If you don't want to rebuild everything, you can, either manually or programmatically, create specific dependecies.